# Mozila Firefox 51.0.1 (New version) Firebug not Working?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I using firebug past one year in Forefox, 51th version console log for javascript not working

Any body know about this solution give me the idea
they told no longer

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firebug** is discontinued. You got automatically switched to the **Firefox DevTools** (with a Firebug theme to make the transition a little easier). Please see the related Mozilla Hacks [blog](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/) post for more info and read the [migration guide](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FTools%2FMigrating_from_Firebug&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHF-AAFsU-K4brETc1mXw5r1rrvoA).

Its better you use Web Developer tool.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

Use **ctrl+Shift+i**

you will get default console and debugging

it's fine.